# Android sync SQLite database with Server database

Tags: android, synchronization

I have created an app with SQLite and now I want to sync the data between SQLite database and server database. How can I achieve this? I have gone through many related questions on SO. Still confused. If I want to use Android SyncAdapter is it necessary to use ContentProvider? That is without the need to access my DB using a ContentProvider. If it is not possible then what to do next? Do I need to create my own ContentProvider?

One more thing, can I use Syncml to achieve this? If yes, then can anybody point me to some reference examples or codes to start with?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android SyncAdapter without ContentProvider. You can pass reference of the Database Manager class and use the helper methods in the onPerformSync() to read/write data.

If you want to use syncml, then server also needs to support it. I had investigated it long back and was not able find any decent open source client/server implementation for syncml. So I implemented my own logic for data synchronization.

Comment: May I know how you did that? What is the logic? I need some help to start with. Piece of code would be really helpful.